# «Something that leads to a contradiction can not be true», is this principle always true?

Tags: logic

> Something that leads to a contradiction can not be true, and if so, the opposite must be true.

In fact, this principle is used in **proof by contradiction**. but, is this principle always true?

Comment: Yes, the rule is: if from P a contradiction follows, then not-P.

Comment: It is true unless it leads to a contradiction. Then the universe explodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the LNC has been accepted as true by most analysts over most of recorded history, there are dissenters, i.e. dialethists. For an academic overview, see ["Paraconsistent Logic"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-paraconsistent/) as well as both the [IEP](https://iep.utm.edu/math-inc/) and [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-inconsistent/) articles on inconsistency-friendly mathematics.

Now paraconsistent logics are not automatically LNC-violators; they're based more on suspension of the argument for the LNC based on "logical explosions." An early example is [relevance logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-relevance/), which waives the kind of disjunctive inference that yields the "irrelevant" deduction of arbitrary conclusions from inconsistent premises. One can be a relevance logician and accept the LNC for some other reason. Still, though, paraconsistent logic is most useful for dialethists because it gives them formal space in which to avoid [trivialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivialism).

Another "way out" is to have multiple flavors of negation. That negation semantics are LNC-theoretic is arguably the main claim, alongside the explosion argument scheme, by virtue of which the LNC has been defended. I.e., to many of us, it seems as if there is a crucial sense of the word *not* and its cognates (e.g. prefixes like *un-*) which makes holding a pair of incompatible assertions to be true sound like a misuse of the word *not*. However, closer inspection at least raises the question of whether this must always be so. For example, one might also suppose that *not*-semantics must conform to double-negation elimination, but [intuitionistic logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/) says otherwise. And [paracompleteness can be regarded as the "dual" of paraconsistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraconsistent_logic#Relation_to_other_logics). So by a quirky back-door approach, one can get a different sense of negation semantics in paraconsistent logic via the alternative such semantics in paracomplete (incl. intuitionistic) logic.

Moreover, consider the difference between [empty nodes and fully empty graphs in graph theory](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EmptyGraph.html). I.e., there is a difference between a graph with however many nodes but no paths, and one with no nodes at all (and one supposes that there is also the degenerate case of a graph with no nodes but to which paths are nevertheless somehow attributed). Perhaps fully empty graphs are akin to C. S. Pierce's [empty spaces](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EmptyGraph.html):

> 1. An empty space is a well-formed diagram.

> 1. If *D* is an empty space, then it is translated into ⊤.

And "⊤" being the symbol for the Truth Value, it might seem to follow that a fully empty graph doesn't represent the negation of any specific truth. Be that as it may, otherwise, there seems to be a graph-theoretic distinction in negation semantics at least as far as empty cases of the node/path pairing is concerned.

Also consider that there are received distinctions between predicative and propositional negation, e.g. it is possible for a horse to be red and not red, as long as the scope of "not red" is not "all of the horse" (it has red parts as well as not-red parts); and then between absence and opposition (passive and active negation). Furthermore, 0/0 is an *indeterminate* expression (per its evaluation), whereas *n*/0 is *undefined*: the former can be evaluated to any value of *n*, whereas the latter has no evaluation. One can subtract zero from itself however times one likes and get zero as a result; one can't subtract zero from some *n* any number of times and get zero.

Or then consider the theory of the negative hyperoperator sequence. If we try to define *x* ↓<sup>*a*</sup> *y* as *x* ↑<sup>-*a*</sup> *y*, two main issues arise. First, we lose out on zeration-as-succession for the ascension operator scheme, since zero is neither positive nor negative in the required manner (or perhaps might be thought of as both). Moreover, trying to compose the negative hyperoperator sequence under the same rubric as the positive one, viz. *x* ↑<sup>*a*</sup> *x* = *x* ↑<sup>*a*+1</sup> 2, does not go through, regardless of whether the succession of the operators goes forward as usual or backwards from *a* = 0 in the descension hypersequence. I.e., imagine that 1 ↑<sup>-1</sup> 1, which would be 1 - 1 = 0, were composed as usual; the result would be 1 ↑<sup>0</sup> 2, or “the second successor of 1,” which is 3; or if 1 ↑<sup>-1</sup> 1 = 1 ↑<sup>-2</sup> 2, we would have ½, which is not 0 either. So the negative hyperoperator sequence, or rather the introduction of the descension operator scheme, is not reducible to negatively signing the ascension schematics.

The “upshot,” then, is that the minus sign as such, and the downward arrow, are not only different glyphs, but seem to have internally distinct negation semantics. This allows us to intuitively grasp how it is that the imaginary unit can be productively composed with itself to form a minus-signed number: *i* is accessed by a negative hyperoperator, an even-root operator, and hence is first a matter of the down-arrow glyphset, and then it yields a minus-signed number, modulo the separate negation semantics for the minus-sign.

Accordingly, proof-by-contradiction might have to be limited to the context of the kind of negation/contradictions that obey "normal" such semantics, but one might be able to infer a different flavor of contradiction from some premise and this wouldn't tell against the premise (at least not in the same way).

Comment: "*What part of NOT don't you understand?*" I guess... Wow.

Comment: @ScottRowe this is gonna sound ridiculous but a lot of my obsession with the topic came from trying to define a god-of-destruction in a fantasy story I was writing 

Comment: A nice, fun answer. Relevance logics typically don't allow you to move from A → ⊥ to ¬A. Usually they treat negation as a primitive modal operator. And of course intuitionistic logic allows A → ⊥ therefore ¬A, but not ¬A → ⊥ therefore A.

Comment: @KristianBerry. So a contradiction *is* problematic (*ex falso quodlibet*)and if one is to *allow* it, we tweak the system to prevent $\bot \to p$ where p is any proposition - possible by e.g. prohibiting *disjunction introduction* aka *addition*. The rest of your post regarding graphs (nodes & paths) went over my head, but still, intersting. Gracias for the answer and the links. Have a nice day.

Comment: @AgentSmith my understanding of EFQ is that it's a syntactic effect (of disjunctive syllogism?), but one question I've had about it is whether we might curtail it by claiming that finite theories don't have "enough" possible sentences available to them, for a proper explosion. So firstly, a difference between explosivity = one random sentence inferrable, vs. *all* random sentences inferrable. (Granted, perhaps we could construe the all-consuming blob as a very large conjunction, externally consolidated "as if" it were a single sentence. But I need a better theory of conjunction, anyway...)

Comment: @KristianBerry, merci beaucoup.

Answer (score 0):

**The very short answer**

Yes, for most applications this is a very useful working assumption.  Treat it as true.

**Longer answer**

No. What you are using is classical logic, which only allows two "truth states", true or false, and assumes the Law of Non-Contradiction, and the Principle of the Excluded Middle (things can only be True or False).

IN CLASSICAL LOGIC, your proposition is always true.  But not all aspects of our universe seem to follow classical logic, and we have shown that there are infinite other logics, many of which do not require the Law of Non-Contradiction.  See this paper for a discussion of logical pluralism:  https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/think/article/abs/guide-to-logical-pluralism-for-nonlogicians/EDFDFA1C9EB65DB71848DABD6B12D877

Pragmatically, in understanding our world, classical logic is a good first assumption. However, sometimes it breaks down.  So the remaining candidates for "One True Logic" are non-classical logics which can encompass multiple other logics, including classical logic, as pragmatic local approximations.

Answer (score -1):

If you'll permit a simpler explanation than **Kristian Berry**'s ...

A *contradiction*, the *issue* therein, revolves around *negation*. If I *negate* the statement "God exists", I mean "God exists" is *false*; this negation looks like "God does *not* exist"

Let's suppose *contradictions* are true, an example of which is "God exists" **and** "God does *not* exist" ( G & ~G).

Notice the logical operator *negation* ("~" before G); if contradictions are true, it does *absolutely nothing* with respect to the *truth value* of the proposition "God exists" (G). *Negation* is *functionally meaningless/inert*.

Now suppose we claim that no, negation does what it's supposed to do (*switch* the truth value from true to false and false to true). G is true (one conjunct) **and** ~G is true (the other conjunct). If so G is false because the negation of G (~G) is true. Taking T = true and F = false, if x is the unknown truth value of a proposition and ~x = T then, x = F (negation) , but if I say x = T also, the conclusion is inevitable, x = T = F. The same applies to G & ~G. The truth value of G is T. If the truth value of ~G is T then, the truth value of G is F (negation). If the truth value of G is represented as g then, g = T = F i.e. T = F. The *distinction true vs. false* is lost and the entire notion of *truth* collapses.

Logics used to handle contradictions are described as contradiction *tolerant* which means, in me book, contradictions are permitted as *conclusions* but they're *not allowed* as *premises* (re *ex falso quodlibet*).  That answers your question I believe.

Comment: I appreciate the effort to turn Kristian Berry's answer into something more understandable for non-logicians such as you and I.  I am not sure you were successful, and I tried my hand at it as well.

Comment: Apologies ... my plan backfired. I'll edit it, not now, but later; check back in about 7 - 8 hours.

Answer (score -2):

"«Something that leads to a contradiction can not be true», is this principle always true?"

Yes, this statement is always true. The proof of its truthness is ofcourse in data (observation).

Its never observed that something both exist and not exist at the same time, in the same place, in the same sense.

Once you get to the atoms, the indivisible parts, the parts that cannot be simplified / broken down any more then the world is binary, things exist or don't exist, thats what our observations tell us.

This is the basis of Aristotelian Logic. Things exist or don't exist, never both, never neither.

The indivisible parts may be "at same time" meaning a thing can exist at some time and don't exist at other times, for example if you destroy a car then the car don't exist any more; at same place, ofcourse you are where you are right now, not also in some other place; in same sense, a person is dead physically but his memory is alive say.

Nobody goes against this fundamental thing. People will argue about what sense one mean that a thing exist (or don't exist) but once the sense, the atoms, are agreed upon everybody agree on a binary / either-or.

As noted above, the truth of all this is in data. As always data should be kept at top and all theories should be derived from it.

Comment: Atif -- you will find, if you study modern physics, that virtual particles (which don not clearly exist or not exist) are a central aspect of how our physics works.  Your Classical Logic categories don not actually constrain our world, only your thinking.

Comment: What you call modern physics has nothing to do with physics aka mechanics, the how; and is just abstract maths. Has nothing to do with real world. How do I know? Unlike many who just read headlines and swallow ready made conclusions I actually looked at data of the experiments. The maths proposed dont fit with data. How? The so-called physicists make placeholder terms they dont even have a definition for to fill holes in their equations. They invented concept of Dark Energy for example. A term without meaning. Chat with me in private because its off-topic here. There is a long list.

Comment: Atif -- your rejecting what physicists say about physics, because it does not fit your Aristotelian presuppositions, is not something I expect to learn  anything useful from.  For a discussion of dogmatism, see this answer:  https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/95735/does-the-bayesian-degree-of-belief-system-result-in-absurd-conclusions/95737#95737

Comment: You want to throw logic out of window, its your choice. It dont make a thing what its not. You look too impressed with big names to use your own head. Like putting a whig on your head dont make you a judge unless you sit in a court listen to people's cases no matter your degrees, a person is not a physicist if he dont do experiments and just sit with a pen and paper have abstract thoughts, do thought experiments, make equations that dont fit even with observations, then go make terms like Zero Point Energy, Dark Energy, Orbitons, Uncertainty Principles, Particle-Wave Duality etc.

Comment: The concept of virtual particles is a made-up concept that has nothing to do with real world. A particle if exist even for a very short period of time do exist during that as much as you and I exist. But the so-called physicists call them virtual because they want them to do only some things during their existence, not all as it would really, because otherwise their equations are proved wrong. Likewise, data shows more gravity in universe than any theory they have suggests, so instead of correcting the equations they introduce made-up terms like Dark Energy.

Comment: Atif -- the physics theories you reject are all based on experimental data.  Your claim they are not -- is a falsehood.  Your claim that they were developed by abstract thinking is also false.  Multiple experiments, over decades, revealed flaws with an Aristotelian and Classical Physics view of the world, and modern physics was the only model which fits that data.  There were generations of physicists who, like you, rejected the data and consequences of that data.  But physics is guided by evidence, not by Aristotelian dogma.

Comment: These terms are not found elsewhere. They have no other usage. They dont even have a definition. Look, always, always and always put data above theories below. Use philosophy for what it is, tool to understand real world.

Comment: No, they are not based on experimental data. Its something you read somewhere and are forwarding it without giving it thought. There are flaws in equations so they dont fit with data, that is why made-up terms are introduced. Tell me whats Dark Energy? Where it comes from? Where it go? How do gravity's effects reach distant objects? If something dont exist how can it affect anything? If something do exist, even for brief time period why its called virtual? Why is concept of observation ill-defined (to fit whatever "physicist" want it to mean at the moment) in QM when its so fundamental to it?

Comment: Atif -- This quote from you "flaws in equations so they don't fit with data" directly and explicitly contradicts "they are not based on experimental data".  Your refuting your own claim, two sentences later, shows an extreme lack of self-evaluation applied to your own assertions.  In cosmology, space appears to have a repulsive feature over long distances, which partially reduces the cumulative effect of gravity.  This produces an energy component to the universe, which is called dark energy.  The repulsion is observed.  The theory as to what causes this is in work, that is prioritizing data.

Comment: Some of the terms in the equations are not defined, they are adhoc fill ins to "match" data. For any equation to be proper each of the terms must be independently defined, that is, have meaning outside of the equations. Each of the things represented by the terms must be able to be checked, measured, verified. Look for concept of _assignments_ and the fudges called _free variables_ when such assignments are not made. You cannot change your definitions half way in your analysis, can you?

Comment: You and your fellow "physicists" throw terms like they don't mean anything and can be made to fit anything you want and then change meaning to anything else you want at any other time. "In cosmology, space appears to have a repulsive feature over long distances, which partially reduces the cumulative effect of gravity." See, you used the term "space" when its not even defined. If its void it cannot do anything. If its made of something that something must be mass or energy (what else is there?) and must have gravity, not anti-gravity so you cannot have Dark Energy anyway.

Comment: Atif-- changing theory based on contrary data is what science does.  You claimed scientists did NOT do this, and now complain that they do.  Your own posts and rationalizations are incoherent and contradictory, and you are unphased by having this pointed out to you.  And no, as an empirical field, science does not start with unquestionable or unmodifiable dogma.  The entities science postulates are based on theory matching data.  Your dismissal of data when it does not match your theory, while also ignoring fallacies and contradictions in your "theory", is just pure dogmatic rationalization.

Comment: There is no contradiction in what I said. There is contradiction in what your equations say. I have nothing against changing equations to match data. Thats however not what those "physicists" do. The equations dont balance because they are not right, thats why a lot of fudging is done. One such is fudging is having free-floating variables, unassigned, meaningless terms. Free Energy is one such example. Space is another. You dont have a definition for space. If its empty it cannot repel. If it has mass/energy it must attract. How would you explain Dark Energy then? Off topic here anyway.